# How to custom view with BarcodeFragLibV2

Tags: android, android-fragments, surfaceview, zxing, android-fragmentactivity

I'm working on an Android application designed with Fragment that's why I'm using the BarcodeFragLib which use the Zxing library.

I'm looking for a way to custom the capture view, adding button and catch the event in my Activity.

If anyone has a hint or an ideas of how to solve my problem is welcome in advance :)

Comment: You must implement IscanResultHandler within your activity

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xamarin, you could to use a event args static that when the code will be captured then you active the event and you will catch the code.

Is like:

```
public class GenericEventArgs<T>:EventArgs
{
    public T Result;
    public GenericEventArgs (T result)
    {
        Result = result;
    }
}
```

and use this form:

```
public static event EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<string>> GetCodeBar_Completed;
if (GetCodeBar_Completed != null) {
        GetCodeBar_Completed (this, new GenericEventArgs<string> (value));
}
```

and subcribe this.

```
PreferencesData.GetCodeBar_Completed += (s, a) => {/*content...*/};
```